# Venn diagram for a relation

Tags: terminology, relations

My high school math book says the following diagram is a [Venn diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram). But I think this is not correct. Is it right? If not, what is the following diagram that represents a relationship called?
[image]

Comment: It is a arrow diagram as well.

Comment: I think you are right, because a Venn diagram has an other role.

Answer (score 3):

It is a perfectly legitimate Venn Diagram which shows two, disjoint sets. They don't have to overlap to be a Venn Diagram. This type of diagram could also be called a mapping diagram because it shows you how the elements of one set (the oval on the left) are mapped to elements of another set (the oval on the right).

Comment: But the diagram doesn't demonstrate disjoint sets, only mappings. X and Y could have elements in common.